# GPUImage initWithAsset only shows last frame

Tags: ios, avfoundation, gpuimage, avasset

I'm trying to initialize GPUImageMovie with an `AVAsset`, which is an `AVMutableComposition`. However, it will only show the last frame after it has run all benchmark frames. If I use initWithURL it works fine, but I don't want to generate a file.

I've also tried creating an `AVAsset` from a file URL with the same result.

```
_movieFile = [[GPUImageMovie alloc] initWithAsset:_myAsset];
_movieFile.runBenchmark = YES;
_movieFile.playAtActualSpeed = YES;

_filterView = [[GPUImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self windowSize]];
```

Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. What I did was creating a `GPUImageMovieWriter` but **not** actually calling `[movieWriter startRecording]`